# Devise: add additional field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm a junior rails developer and I'm attempting to add one additional field, `name`, to my `Users` table.

In `/views/registrations/new` I have

```
<%= f.text_field :name,  class:"form-control", :value => params[:name]  %>
```

In my application controller I've added:

```
before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters

    ## To permit attributes while registration i.e. sign up (app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) << :name << :sex 

    ## To permit attributes while editing a registration (app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb)
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) << :name << :sex
  end
```

But after the form is validated and submitted it doesn't the save value found in the `name` field.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27910381/rails-devise-doesnt-save-extra-input-fields-to-database) solution didn't work for me.

Comment: What do the logs say?

Comment: Noyhing. It save my user. But doesn't save user.name

Answer (score -1):

You can try this syntax

```
def configure_devise_params
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) {|u| u.permit(:name, :sex)} 
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) {|u| u.permit(:name, :sex)}
end
```